# ec2 cli api not usable within vpc?

Tags: amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, vpc

I have some instances with an EC2 VPC (using only ip addresses from RFC 1918) that need to use some services of EC2 via CLI interface (ec2-describe-instances, ec2-run-instances, etc)

I can't get it to work : my understanding is that the service point of the CLI interface is located somewhere in AWS cloud and my requests originating from an RFC1918 address are not routable in the AWS cloud between EC2 service point and my instance.

Is that correct ?

Is my only solution to install a NAT instance within my VPC (I would like to avoid it) ? Or could I get a way to remap this Ec2 service point within my VPC on a RFC1918 address

Any help welcome ! 
Thanks in advance
didier

Answer (score 0):

You can give the instance an elastic IP address and get outbound access to other publicIPs, like the EC2 API endpoint.  Make sure your security group doesn't allow any inbound traffic from the Internet.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use an EIP, you can launch an instance in a VPC with a publicIP address.  more here: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/08/additional-ip-address-flexibility-in-the-virtual-private-cloud.html

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your answerand hints. So, no chance to get the contrary: i.e have a mapping of the EC2 API endpoint with the addressing plan of my VPC ? That would better much our security requirements. regards. Didier